# create an array with the values of the nodes at a level

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I have to create an array that contains the values of nodes in a level passed as parameter. The function `createArray` has to return an array containing the values of the nodes at the level passed as parameter. My code is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

struct node* newNode(int data) {
    struct node* node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    node->data = data;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;

    return node;
}

int numNodesLevel(struct node* root, int level) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        if (level == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        return numNodesLevel(root->left, level - 1) + numNodesLevel(root->right, level - 1);
    }
}

int max(int a, int b) {
    if(a > b) {
        return a;
    }
    else {
        return b;
    }
}

int height(struct node* root) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL) {
            return 0;
        }
        return max(height(root->left), height(root->right)) + 1;
    }
}

int maxNodesLevel(struct node* root) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        int max = 0;
        int h = height(root);
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i <= h; i++) {
            if (numNodesLevel(root, i) > max) {
                max = numNodesLevel(root, i);
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
}

void fill(struct node* root, int* A, int level, int* i) {
    if (root != NULL) {
        if (level == 0) {
            A[*i] = root->data;
            *i = *i + 1;
        }
        fill(root->left, A, level - 1, i);
        fill(root->right, A, level - 1, i);
    }
}

int* createArray(struct node* root, int level) {
    if (root != NULL) {
        int *A = (int*)calloc(maxNodesLevel(root), sizeof(int));
        int i = 0;
        fill(root, A, level, &i);
        return A;
    }
}

int main(){
    struct node* root = newNode(12);
    root->left = newNode(3);
    root->right = newNode(16);
    root->left->left = newNode(2);
    root->left->right = newNode(2);
    root->right->left = newNode(2);
    root->right->right = newNode(22);
    printf("%d", createArray(root,1));
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The result should be 3,16 which are the values of the nodes at level 1, but it gives me different numbers like 22721648. These numbers are different every time I run the code, so I think there must be something wrong in the way I use pointers, but I can't figure out where is the error.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: What does `createRoot` return? What are you attempting to print? How would you print any other array?

Comment: `printf("%d", createArray(root,1));` : `createArray` return `int *`, not `int`.

Comment: Have you tried just printing the tree, to make sure that the tree is correct, before you start doing anything more?  You can't print an array with a single call to `printf()`, so the output at the end is broken — for multiple reasons, but all of them indicate that the `printf()` line must be rewritten completely (and it will cease to be a single line; probably at least one variable declaration and a loop control line and a different `printf()`).

Comment: The `#include`s are absolutely necessary for a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is correct, but only mistake here is createArray() returns an array and you are considering it as int.
Add following code instead of printf() and it will work.

```
int level = 1, *arr;
arr = createArray(root, level);
for(int i = 0; i < 2 * level; i++){
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);
}
```

Hope it will help !!